# Setting member property on Select new Class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have defined a custom class (BRDResult) that I would like to use for returning data into from the EF select, so that only few columns are returned from the query, rather than everything from all included tables.
The class has simple properties in the form of string, int etc

```
results.Select(
            batchClaim => new BRDResult
            {
                ClaimSystemNumber = batchClaim.ClaimSystemNumber,
                TotalAllowedAmount = batchClaim.Claim.ClaimHeaderResult
                .Where(header => header.ClaimSystemNumber == claimSystemNumber && header.RunNumber == batchRunNumber).Sum(header => header.ClaimDetailResult.Select(detail => detail.AllowedAmount).Sum()),
                CisDetailLineNumber = batchClaim.Claim.ClaimHeaderResult
                .Where(header => header.ClaimSystemNumber == claimSystemNumber && header.RunNumber == batchRunNumber)
                .SelectMany(head => head.ClaimDetailResult)
                .Select(det => det.CisDetailNumber)
                .FirstOrDefault(),
                ReimbursementMethod = batchClaim.Claim.ClaimHeaderResult.Where(header => header.ClaimSystemNumber == claimSystemNumber && header.RunNumber == batchRunNumber).SelectMany(head => head.ClaimDetailResult).Select(det => det.ReimbursementMethod).FirstOrDefault(),
                PaymentStatusCode = batchClaim.Claim.ClaimMHeaderResult.Where(header => header.ClaimSystemNumber == claimSystemNumber && header.RunNumber == batchRunNumber).SelectMany(head => head.ClaimMDetailResult).Select(det => det.FinalEapgNumber.ToString()).FirstOrDefault(),
                PaymentPercent = batchClaim.Claim.ClaimMHeaderResult.Where(header => header.ClaimSystemNumber == claimSystemNumber && header.RunNumber == batchRunNumber).SelectMany(head => head.ClaimMDetailResult).Select(det => det.PaymentPercent).FirstOrDefault(),
                AllowedAmount = batchClaim.Claim.ClaimHeaderResult.Where(header => header.ClaimSystemNumber == claimSystemNumber && header.RunNumber == batchRunNumber).SelectMany(head => head.ClaimDetailResult).Select(det => det.AllowedAmount).FirstOrDefault(),
                PendCode = batchClaim.Claim.ClaimHeaderResult.Where(header => header.ClaimSystemNumber == claimSystemNumber && header.RunNumber == batchRunNumber).SelectMany(head => head.ClaimDetailResult).Select(det => det.PendCode).FirstOrDefault(),
                OptimizerReturnCode = batchClaim.Claim.ClaimMHeaderResult.Where(header => header.ClaimSystemNumber == claimSystemNumber
               && header.RunNumber == batchRunNumber).Select(head => head.OptimizerReturnCode.ToString()).FirstOrDefault()

            });
```

I know the FirstOrDefault is restricting pulling back only 1 row of type BRDResult, when in fact I need multiple detail records to be pulled back.

But, because the left hand side member property like CisDetailLineNumber are simple string properties or so and the right hand side, refer to a ICollection.certain property using a Select which returns an IEnumerable itself, I'm forced to use FirstOrDefault to get the build working.

Would be nice to get multiple detail records from this, with the mentioned columns having values in each record correspondingly.

Really stuck on this since 2 days now. Any help is much appreciated.

```
Input -> ClaimSystemNumber = 1369 and RunNumber = 1 (these are used in   repository.Query itself and returned entire data using just .Select())
Then the results.Select pulls a filtered column data from that

Current Output -> Single record in IEnumerable<BRDResult> with values
{ClaimSystemNumber = 1369,
CisDetailLineNumber = 1,
ReimbursementMethod = "APC",
PaymentStatusCode = "1",
PaymentPercent = 1.0,
AllowedAmount = 11,
PendCode = "23",
OptimizerReturnCode = "WE"}

Expected Result -> 2 records with different values in all the properties as shown above as detail table has 2 records matching given ClaimSystemNumber and RunNumber combination.
```

Comment: Could please show a sample input, a desired output and a current output?

Comment: @FirstStep Updated the original question for requested details. Hope that helps